# how to use x_years to convert a year from a locale in rails and put it on a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to put a year today to 20 years ago and put it on the dropdown and use the locale in rails

```
This is my ja.yml

datetime:
distance_in_words:
  x_years:
    one: 1年
    other: "%{count}年"
```

How this thing put into a year dropdown starting from this year until 20 years ago in rails

```
Example Dropdown:

2018年
2017年
2016年
2015年
2014年
so on........
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: no i didn't try

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get started:

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year:  Date.today.year - 20) %>
```

More info: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year